# adding multiple input types in jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, calculated-field

I'm trying to add sum of check boxed field with one text input field, which may be left blank or filled in. I'm almost there, but am missing something!  I can get the checkboxes to add successfully, and the number input field, but can't get the two of them to add together for a grand total. This script works individually without the code below the comment line where I try to add.  Any help is much appreciated.

```js
$(".amt").change(function() {
        var amttotal = 0;
    
        $('.amt').each(function() {
           var value = Number($(this).val());
        if (!isNaN(value)) amttotal += value;
        });
    $("#amttotal").html(amttotal.toFixed(0));
});

$(".levels").change(function() {
    var chktotal = 0;
    $(".levels:checked").each(function() {
        chktotal += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
    });
    $("#chktotal").html(chktotal.toFixed(0));
});

// want to add two totals for a grand total
$(".amt",".levels").change(function() {
    var total = chktotal + amttotal;
     });
 $("#total").html(total.toFixed(0));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sponsorship">

<p>Sponsorship Level: (check all that apply):</p>
<ul><li><input class="levels" type="checkbox" name="admiral"  onclick="" data-price="0"> Admiral’s Level $2000+ - fill in the blank <input class="amt" type="number" name="amount" min="2000" max="5000" step="100" onclick=""> </li>
<li><input class="levels" type="checkbox" name="commodore" data-price="1500" onclick=""> Commodore’s Level - $1500</li>
<li><input class="levels" type="checkbox" name="captain" data-price="1000" onclick=""> Captain’s Level - $1000</li>
<li><input class="levels" type="checkbox" name="master" data-price="500" onclick=""> Master’s Level - $500</li>
<li><input class="levels" type="checkbox" name="Commodore" data-price="100" onclick=""> Mate’s Level - $100</li>

<li><input class="levels" type="checkbox" name="closing" data-price="750" onclick=""> Closing Dinner Table - $750</li>
<li><input class="levels" type="checkbox" name="cruise" data-price="500" onclick=""> Riverboat Cruise - $500</li>
</ul>
        
        <p>Checkbox total (hide or remove):<span id="chktotal"></span></p>
      <p>fill blank total (hide or remove):<span id="amttotal"></span></p>
        
<p><span style="background-color:#FF6; font-weight:bold">TOTAL DUE: $ <span id="total"></span></span></p>
```

I've tried to shorten and combine ealier on, too, but no success:

```
    $(".amt", ".levels").change(function() {
   var amttotal = 0;

    $('.amt').each(function() {
       var value = Number($(this).val());
    if (!isNaN(value)) amttotal += value;
    });
var chktotal = 0;
$(".levels:checked").each(function() {
    chktotal += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
});
var total = chktotal + amttotal;

$("#total").html(total.toFixed(0));
});
```

Comment: Welcome to the community! Can you provide details on what "no success" mean? Do you have any errors or result differs from the  expected one?

Comment: no success means it didn't work.  ooking at it again , I'm missing an } at the end!L

Comment: good thing you ooked at it.  ;-)

Comment: the missing end mark wasn't the problem... Still can't get it working. Going to take a break from it for a few days and see if fresher eyes help.